# Remove Google AdSense ads in specific countries

Tags: ads, adsense

How can I only show the google AdSense ads on my website when my website is accessed from a certain country.
Is there is  such option in the google AdSense dashboard.
Or should I do that with code and how can I do that

I tired searching for this option in the dashboard but i could not find it.